# React, change state works only for one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my react app. I have form  with 2 components (two separate pickers), and I need to change component state when the date is incorrect. Here is the code:

```
    constructor(props: EditFormProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isValidDate: true,
        isValidTime: true
    } as EditFormState;

    this.validateDate = this.validateDate.bind(this);
    this.validateTime = this.validateTime.bind(this);
}

render() {
       return (
           <div>
                <FormSection title={FLIGHT_DATES} className="flight-dates">
                    <div>
                        <DateRange validateDate={this.validateDate} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <TimeOfDate validateTime={this.validateTime} />
                    </div>
                </FormSection>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


private validateDate(isValidDate: boolean) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        isValidDate: isValidDate,
    } as EditFormState);
}

private validateTime(isValidTime: boolean) {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        isValidTime: isValidTime,
    } as EditFormState);
}
```

When I have only one function like validateDate its set state for isValidDate without problem, but when i have 2 functions (validateDate and validateTime) i got proper parameter for validateDate but state is always the same (it's working fine for isValidTime). When I change positions in FormSection  and TimeOfDate is 1st I have same problem for isValidTime state and isValidDate it woks good. So probably I have some bigger problem in my project, but maybe there is other way to set this state or pass parameter from DateRange or TimeOfDay?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code, do you mind posting the code of `FormSection` ?

Comment: There is span with proper class name and another div, when I delete FormSection its still same situation. Can I make one function with two parameters to change selected state or change states to properties somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem with your code is that you are reading from `this.state` inside the `this.setState()` call.

In this case `this.state` is not guaranteed to contain the up-to-date state.

You should pass a function to `this.setState()` rather than an object. E.g:

```
private validateDate(isValidDate: boolean) {
  this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
    ...prevState,
    isValidDate: isValidDate
  })
}
```

More info in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)
.

Comment: "you are reading from this.state inside the this.setState() call." He doesn't.

Comment: @Yozi Sorry, but it is clear from his example that he does. How do you reckon otherwise?

Comment: `this.setState({...this.state})` is the same as `const newState = {...this.state}; this.setState(newState);`. In fact, he read nothing in the setState exactly, your wording deceived me. But it is right, that he read wrong state in his validation function

Comment: Guys, one more question. How can I move validateDate and validateTime methods to separate files (I need to use it in multiple components)? Because I don't know how to change state of main component when I move this methods to separate files.

Comment: @jager91 you could use a [higher-order component pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for this.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to remove `...this.state` from  the validation functions

Maybe you call both validation function in the same time-frame? React merges multiple setState functions into one, so it is possible that you have something like this:

set newIsValidDate => set newIsValidTime *and* setOldIsValidTime